# Web service performance optimization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance

Scenario:
ASP.NET MVC web application calls Java web service requesting 2 years worth of data. Below is the size of response from web service:

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      937        (headers:396; body:541)
Bytes Received:  689,300        (headers:338; body:688,962)
```

This takes around almost 2 minute. This causes the ASP.NET to run slow and as a result users frustration. Have spoken with Java guys and they have
done their best to optimize the performance.

Could someone please help me with what would be the best way to optimize the web service call to third party?  Below is list of things I've done and
hasn't help:

1. Broken down the 2 years data to 1 year each with ASYC call.
2. Have asked the Java guys to reduce the message size so that payload is
   small.

Still the performance hasn't increased.

If I create a async VOID method which simply request a 2 years data and populates cache, would this work? Main concern is whether the Login process needs to wait
for this VOID method to complete.

Comment: I made a lot of similar tasks and asp.net is not run slow. Maybe you need to investigate the point that make it run slow. Is a memory issue on the hardware, is some kind of lock on the sql data that lock the rest of the users, is something else ? Also need to define slow, is not return until the task ends, is return something, what ? Even a bad sql setup can do that, if you change the sql thread priority. Do you have access to the server to see what is making slow ?

Comment: do you really need a different two years of data for each user?

Comment: Firstly you should monitor the http channel, to highlight the time between you sent the request, and the time when the first byte of the response are returned. Then, measure the duration (and throughput) of the response transfert. This will show you what exactly is taking time

Comment: Agree with @Aristos and Steve B above. You need to do some profiling to find out what part of the process is slow before making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems aren't easy to debug from remote, however you should first start with measure where you lose most of your time. Is it in the call to the Java service of in your processing. Add performace counter to your code/ or logging to see where can improve most. Next you can exchange parts like the webservice call with a stub and see if your performance is better, now you know where you have to change your performance.

Comment: Theperformace is slow on java,need to make asynchronous call and populate local cache as part of login.but this call should run on background, fire and forget.it should not Henderson login process. when user clicks on  page where two year is few. then load from local cache

Comment: Is above possible? What I don't know is how to run background asynchronous call in asp.net

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can start a thread when the user logs on to your site which puts the data into your session, or cache.

Comment: could you share a code how this can be achieved, thanks peer. Would not the asp.net wait for the function to complete?